# Proving Continuity using epsilon-delta on an interval

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, epsilon-delta

I am having trouble proving the continuity of:

$$f(x)=\frac{2x^5-98}{(x-9)(x-1)}$$

in the interval $[2,8]$.

I'm trying to use an epsilon-delta proof to get to the result but I keep getting stuck.

My proof so far looks like:

Suppose $|x-c|< \delta$ and let $\delta=1$.

\begin{align}|f(x)-f(c)|
&= \left|\frac{2x^5-98}{(x-9)(x-1)}-\frac{2c^2-98}{(c-9)(c-1)}\right|\\\\
&=\left|\frac{(2x^5-98)(c-9)(c-1)-(2c^5-98)(x-9)(x-1)}{(x-9)(x-1)(c-9)(c-1)}\right|\\\\
&\leq \left|(2x^5-98)(c-9)(c-1)-(2c^5-98)(x-9)(x-1)\right|\\\\
&=\left|2x^2c^2(x^3-c^3)+20xc(x^4-y^4)+18(x^5-c^5)+98(x^2-c^2)+980(c-x)\right|\\
\end{align}

From here I think to use the triangle inequality and drag out a common factor of $|x-c|$ but even if I do that I still get stuck and don't know how to use my other assumption that $\delta=1$.

Am I on the right track or is there a more elegant way of showing continuity using epsilon-delta?

Comment: Can you make use of limit rules for sums, products, quotients, and so on?

Comment: ^ Seriously. There is no reason, aside from masochism, to prove that this function is continuous from first principles.

Comment: @Siminore Ah! Thank you!